# How to upload multiple files using spring mvc and ajax

Tags: java, jquery, spring

I am trying to upload multiple files but getting 400 error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400
>   (Bad Request)

Could any anybody please give a solution?
This is my HTML form

```
<input type="file" name="img" multiple id="upsnap_map" />
```

this is my JS code

```
var formData = new FormData();
//
    formData.append("user",user);

var files=$('#upsnap_map').prop('files')
for(var i=0; i < files.length; i++){
    formData.append('upImage1[' + i + ']', files[i]);
    //formData.append("upImage1", files);
    formData.append("imagePath",$("#upsnap_map")[0].files[0].name);
}
```

This is my java code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)   
        public void upload(@RequestParam ArrayList<Object> upImage1,HttpSession session,HttpServletResponse response,
                    HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam String imagePath) throws IllegalStateException, IOException, 
        {
```

This is my ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url:"upload",
        type : "POST",
        async:false,
        data:formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success:function(data){
```

Comment: how many files users can upload at a time?

Comment: @bRIMOs ajax request added

Comment: @utkarsh31 I tried with 3 files

Comment: We had the same requirement but number of files were limited to 5, we customized the code and used [link](http://www.journaldev.com/2573/spring-mvc-file-upload-example-single-multiple-files) to upload the files..Will this work for you?

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-multipart

Comment: why using `@RequestParam ArrayList<Object> upImage1 `? 
I think you should use the array of multipart data file like `@RequestParam("upImage1") MultipartFile[] upImage1`

Comment: @bRIMOs I tried but same error